# do I have to get my app approved by Paypal before I can use Sandbox for testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using rails and the [Adaptive Payments SDK](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-ruby) to implement a chained payment but I keep getting an error when I make an API request saying that my API credentials are wrong.

I double checked that my API credentials are definitely entered correctly. I had obtained them from these instructions:

> To access the API credentials/ certificate information that we’ll use, log in to PayPal, mouse over the Profile tab, select My Settings, then click on the “My selling tools” tab on the left side of the page.  On the “API access” line click update, then click “Request API credentials”, make sure “Request API signature” is selected and then click “Agree and Submit”.  Credentials should be there.

But the response I keep getting is as follows:

```
{
  :responseEnvelope => {
    :timestamp => "2015-09-06T11:50:35.612-07:00",
    :ack => "Failure",
    :correlationId => "5600f74376d7f",
    :build => "17820627" },
  :error => [{
    :errorId => 520003,
    :domain => "PLATFORM",
    :subdomain => "Application",
    :severity => "Error",
    :category => "Application",
    :message => "Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect." }]
}
```

I'm not certain that it's not my code that's wrong but I suspect its because my application to get an APP-ID has not been approved yet. So even though I inputted the Sandbox APP-ID in my paypal.yml file, do I still need to wait until my app is approved or is it something else (from what I've provided?)

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/):

> Check your account status. Login to PayPal. Go to your PayPal Profile
>   and click My settings. Confirm that your Account type is either
>   Premier or Business, or upgrade your account.
>
> Check your API settings. Click My selling tools. Expand Selling online
>   if needed and check API access. Click Update and Add or edit API
>   permission or View API signature.
>
> Test your integration using the PayPal Sandbox, as described in
>   Testing Classic API Calls. All Adaptive API calls in the Sandbox must
>   have the following standard value as the App ID:
>
> APP-80W284485P519543T

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I do have a PayPal Business account, obtained my API credentials, and am using the sandbox API ID :(